# Form zera valores maiores que 999,99

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, aplicação-web

Estou passando por um problema que nunca vi antes. Tenho a esperança de que alguém tenha visto e possa me ajudar.

Eu estou trabalhando com asp.net mvc 5, e enviando um form via post para meu controller.

Meu model:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form action="@Url.Action("Create","DadosManuais")" method="get" class="form-horizontal">
meus campos aqui...
</div>
```

Meu controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(DadosManuaisCreate dados){
     Algumas linhas de código...
}
```

Estou usando também jquery para criar as máscaras no model:

```
@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
$("#periodo").inputmask("mm/yyyy");
            $("#tacGestor").maskMoney({ showSymbol: true, symbol: "R$", 
                decimal: ",", thousands: "." });
            $("#vlEsperado").maskMoney({ showSymbol: true, symbol: "R$", 
                decimal: ",", thousands: "." });
            $("#vlAdquirido").maskMoney({ showSymbol: true, symbol: "R$", 
                decimal: ",", thousands: "." });
            $("#selic").maskMoney({ showSymbol: true, symbol: "R$", decimal: 
                ",", thousands: "." });
            $("#premioSelic").maskMoney({ showSymbol: true, symbol: "R$", 
                decimal: ",", thousands: "." });
            $("#seguro").maskMoney({ showSymbol: true, symbol: "R$", 
                decimal: ",", thousands: "." });
            $("#despesas").maskMoney({ showSymbol: true, symbol: "R$", 
                decimal: ",", thousands: "." });
            $("#naoIdentificados").maskMoney({ showSymbol: true, symbol: 
                "R$", decimal: ",", thousands: "." });
            $("#qtdContratosAtivos").inputmask("9{1,3}.9{1,3}.9{1,3}");
        });
</script>   
}
```

Notem que ao final do comando em jquery, há um parametro "**thousands: "." }**"

Isso diz que, para milhares, será usado o ponto (".") para dividir.

Meu problema acontece quando pressiono o botão submit. o Objeto é instanciado por parâmetro no controller, mas os campos que contém números maiores que 999,99 são zerados.

Olhe só:

[image: Erro]

Retirei o parâmetro "**thousands: "." }**" e o problema parou de ocorrer:

[image: Erro 2]

Como contornar esse problema sem precisar retirar minha máscara?

Muito grato!

PS: Nenhum dado postado aqui é real. São todos usados para simular uma inserção no sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisa formatar os dados **antes** de enviar ao controller, pois o json parser usado por ele **não** interpreta os pontos usados para dividir os múltiplos de 1000.

Então:

```
$( '#idDoForm' ).submit( () => {
   ///Quando o form for enviado
   let $inputs = $( '.formatar' );
   ///Coloque essa classe em todos os campos que vão zerados caso passem de 1000
   $inputs.each( (indice, input) => { 
       ///Para cada input com a classe 'formatar'
       let $input = $(input);

       ///Trocamos todos os pontos por nada
       $input.val( $input.val().replace(/\./g,''));
   })

   ///Submit
   return true;
})
```

**Edit :**

```
var submit = false;
$( '#idDoForm' ).submit( () => {
   ///Toda a logica de antes aqui...

   if(!submit)
       setTimeout( () => {
           submit = true;
           $( '#idDoForm' ).submit();
       },300);//Vamos dar um tempo para o jQuery mudar o form
   ///Submit
   return submit;

})
```

Comment: Eu consegui entender o que pode estar acontecendo, mas não funcionou :(. O script parece estar sendo executado depois do código do controller. Eu lembro que anteriormente funcionava, mas algo que eu alterei fez os dados começarem a ser zerados.

Comment: @Csorgo editei a resposta, deve haver outra maneira de resolver isso, mas por hora deve funcionar assim.

Comment: Não funfou ainda :( Será que existe uma solução no back end em c#?

Comment: @Csorgo **todos** os inputs tem  um `name` correspondente a uma propriedade da classe ?

Comment: Sim @I Dunno. O 'id' também. Não sei se há algum conflito entre eles, mas coloquei para evitar muitas referencias diferentes para o mesmo elemento.